# Javascript | Do after For Loop

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a function after a for loop action finish, any orientation please ?

This is my code :

```
       Function1: function () {
            var $this = this;
            $this.Action();
            var l = $this.list.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {                
            Function2(i)
            }

             function Function2(i){
              axios.post('/api', $this.list[i])          
              .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
              });
             };                     
             },
```

I would like ot call `$this.notAction()` when `i > l || i == l`

Comment: I'd start by fixing your indentation. Makes it very hard to read currently.

Comment: It's unclear why what you're asking for would be a problem. If you want to call a function then call a function. Can you be more specific about what your actual problem is please?

Comment: Thank you for ur interest. I want to call $this.notAction() when my Function2(i) loop finishs. It works fine now with async/await

Comment: @yassinej ah ok. Seems like you perhaps hadn't realised that AJAX requests are asynchronous. So without async/await the loop would be finished but the requests themselves would still be happening. You can always use Promise.all() instead to detect when the requests end...then they would still occur in parallel instead of sequentially, which would make it complete faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **async/await**

```js
Function1: async function () {
 var $this = this;
 $this.Action();
 var l = $this.list.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {                
   await Function2(i)
 }
 $this.notAction();

  async function Function2(i){
   try {
    await axios.post('/api', $this.list[i]);
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
  };                     
}
```

Comment: This code is syntactically invalid and doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: works fine thank you. Why it's syntactically invalid?

Comment: I edited after he put that. I put async await wrong. @yassinej

Answer (score 1):

Just check when the last call was executed, since *i* will never be greater than *l*. Also use the normal functions in a [POST](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call with jQuery.

```
Function1: function () {
    var $this = this;
    $this.Action();
    var l = $this.list.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {                
        var p = Function2(i);
        p.done( function() {
           if ( i == ( l - 1 ) ) {
               $this.notAction();
           } 
        });
    }

    function Function2(i){
        return axios.post('/api', $this.list[i])          
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };                     
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work..

```
for (var i = 0; i <= l; i++) {    
if(i==l){
$this.notAction();
break;
}
Function2(i);
}
```